# Forked process goes in wrong path

Tags: c, ubuntu, operating-system, fork

I have an assignment in C Language; the requirement is that I am given number of students, everyone has 2 grades midterm grade and final grade my task is to calculate the number of students who passed. But I will use forking; we will fork Teaching Assistants to separately choose whether a student should pass or not and the number of Teaching Assistants will be passed on terminal.

Everything is fine. I wrote the code, but I noticed something very weird, I got a segmentation fault which is so weird because I am sure I am not accessing wrong memory. I tried to print something (line 53) and I found that this line is printed 4 times actually, which is equal to number of children + parent, although this line above the fork(). My code creates more than one process (TA) and every TA takes a partition and calculate number of passed students and exit with this code and on parent I make for loop and wait until any child dies so I print its exit code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int Number_of_TAs = atoi(argv[1]);
    int leastgrade = atoi(argv[2]);
    int size_of_array = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int last_visited = 0;
    int ind = 0;



    FILE* ptr;
    char ch;
 
    // Opening file in reading mode
    ptr = fopen("students.txt", "r");
 
    if (NULL == ptr) {
        printf("file can't be opened \n");
    }
 

    do {
        ch = fgetc(ptr);
        size_of_array = 2 * ((int)ch - 48);
        break;
 
    } while (ch != EOF);

 
    fclose(ptr);
    int arr_of_grades[size_of_array]; 
    int arr_of_grades2[size_of_array/2];


    
   FILE *myFile;
   myFile = fopen("students.txt", "r");

    int *dummy;
    fscanf(myFile, "%d", &dummy);
    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
        fscanf(myFile, "%d", &arr_of_grades[i]);
    
    int index2 = 0;
    printf("%d", size_of_array);
    printf(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i< size_of_array; i=i+2)
    {
        arr_of_grades2[index2] = arr_of_grades[i] + arr_of_grades[i+1];
        index2 = index2 + 1;
        
    
    }


    fclose(myFile);


    int pid, stat_loc;
    int passed_students = 0;
    int partion = size_of_array / (2 * Number_of_TAs );
    for (int i=0; i< Number_of_TAs; i++)
    {  
        pid = fork();
        ind = ind + partion;
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {

        for (int i = ind; i< ind + partion; i++)
           { 
            if (arr_of_grades2[i]>=leastgrade )
                passed_students = passed_students + 1;
           }
    exit(passed_students);
    }

    else
    {   
        int sid;
        for (int i = 0; i<Number_of_TAs; i++)
        {
            sid = wait(&stat_loc);
            if(!(stat_loc & 0x00FF))
            printf(stat_loc>>8);
            printf(" ");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am a newbie in C so I didn't try many things

Comment: You need to check the value of `fork()` and do something different in the two processes. Right now, both processes continue the loop and both create new children, which ...

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault issue may happen at any array access with the wrong index.

In your case, it may happen at the first 2 lines:

```
int Number_of_TAs = atoi(argv[1]);
int leastgrade = atoi(argv[2]);
```

if you execute the program without the 2 parameters.

Another issue of your program is that you should move the if-else statement where you check the pid inside the for loop where you create the processes with the fork() otherwise it creates more processes than expected.